# Chrome alert/prompt displays off the screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

An alert/prompt called from chrome extension background pake is shown off the screen (or partially in top left screen). This bug has been fixed in canary build by now, see
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113899 , but I need to get it working as soon as possible. Do you have any ideas how to work this around using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm talking about this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jfiakckbklmccchjegnnojbalafebakb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't position the alert or prompt dialogs in browsers. You have to wait for the bug fix to propagate to the stable branch.

An alternative option is to inject an HTML lightbox into the current tab but that would be a lot of additional work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to further investigate the canary source code, found at the Chromium project on Google Code.

The issue is reported on [the Chromium issues page](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113899), and the fix seem to be found at [this revision on the Chromium sources](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=127890).

You can check out the diff and compile a workaround based on their solution.